# Magento 2 Get Product Url For Specific Store

Tags: product-urls, magento-2.1.8, elasticsearch

I have **multi stores** enabled in my Magento instance. I am trying to get **product url** for each store as I need to **index** data in **Elasticsearch**.

What I have tried but not getting the result with store appended in url.

```
$productId = 2;
$storeId = 4;
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
$product->setStoreId($storeId)->getUrlModel()->getUrlInStore($product, ['_escape' => true]);
```

I expect result as

```
http://example.com/mystorecode/product1.html
```

Where as I get the result

```
http://example.com/product1.html
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also looking for the same query.

Comment: No. So I did a patchy solution which I have added as an answer. You can try it out. It worked out for me.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I think below solution will work fine if you don't want to use object manager :
`$storeUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);

$productUrl = $storeUrl .$productData->getUrlKey();`

Here `$productData` should be filtered with store id to bring store vise data.

Answer (score 2):

From the Magento2 root, you can run below code inside any custom php file.

```
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('admin');
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$productId = 184294;
$storeId = 27;
$product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
echo $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getUrlModel()->getUrlInStore($product, ['_escape' => true]);
```

Comment: How to get current product URL of current store in block? I am using 

public function getCurrentProduct() {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

but it's give default URL.

Answer (score 0):

From Admin > Stores > Configuration > Web > Url Options > Set "Add Store Code to Urls" to "Yes".

Comment: This option is enabled.

Comment: I have just checked in my local system and your code working fine for me.

Comment: What is your magento version ? Are you trying to load product Object In Backend ?

Comment: My magetno version is 2.1.8 and yes i am run my code inside admin area in custom php file.

Comment: Sorry dude not working for me. If you are using some other code paste in your answer.

Comment: See my another answer with code

Answer (score 0):

They patchy solution for my working

```
$storeUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,$isSecure);
$productUrlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
$this->scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
$productSuffix = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
$productUrl = $storeUrl . $productUrlKey . $productSuffix;
```

**Note:** Not recommend to use object manager. This shows my lazyness :)